# How to view the app directory from iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I try to find out how I can look into app directory from my iphone app. Is there a way see the folder structure of my app within xcode?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: So you wanna know how your app looks like when it is installed on your device or simulator? Or you want to show it in your app and you need an API to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just gonna try answering. How about logging it, like this:

```
    //App Directory & Directory Contents
   NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  
   NSLog(@"App Directory is: %@", appFolderPath);
   NSLog(@"Directory Contents:\n%@", [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: appFolderPath]);
```

or

Inside Xcode:

- Window > Organizer > Projects
- Select Project
- "Derived Data" has a small arrow, it will reveal the location in Finder

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can see a bundle (.app):

1. Ctrl + Click on .app in the Project Navigator in Xcode.
2. Select "Show in Finder"
3. Ctrl + Click on .app file in Finder
4. Select "Show Package Contents"

Answer (score 1):

You have to run it in your simulator, and then go check the folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/
```

There will be a subfolder for every version of iOS you have worked with. Get into the folder of the current version of iOS you are working with, and there will be a subfolder called Applications, and inside it there'll be a lot of subfolders with weird names. Check them one by one until you find the one that contains your App :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to archive your project first:

```
Select the device instead of the simulator (you don't have to plug a device in first).
Go to: Product -> Archive.
Open your Organizer (right upper corner).
Go to the Archive and right-click on your archived project, click on "Show in Finder".
```

In the Organizer when you have selected your project xcode tells you how big the app will be on appstore. The actual size if half as big as it's shown.